# Ext Js 4 - Grid cell to cell drag drop?

Tags: javascript, extjs, drag-and-drop, extjs4

Is it possible to implement a drag drop from one grid cell to another gird cell?
eg. Drag a grid cell from grid1 to another grid cell on grid2?

Any thoughts on this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hey, I have a similar requirements.  Any new update on this issue?

Answer (score 1):

This [example](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-3.4.0/examples/dd/field-to-grid-dd.html) (Field to Grid Drag and Drop) should be a little more helpful. In this example the drop onto a cell portion is covered. It also provides an example of a specialized drag zone, which I believe you should be able to tweak to cover the drag from a cell portion of your problem.

Sorry that I cannot provide much more than a lead, but that is not a problem I have specifically had to tackle. I would encourage you to post your answer when you figure it all out, though.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, see : [Ext JS 4 Examples](http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/examples/) : [Grid to Grid DnD](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.7-gpl/examples/dd/dnd_grid_to_grid.html)

Comment: yes this is dragging a row to another grid. I want to drag a cell itslef and drop on another cell.